# Unable to request maven dependencies through ant

Tags: maven, https, ant, dependency-management, ivy

Working on Ubuntu 18.04 on an ANT project. It seems that maven recently required people to make https requests instead of http requests, but I am unsure how to change this configuration. A friend on OSX has not run into this issue. following the links in the error message takes me to this page.

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can update the repository links on your pom.xml file. It looks like this

```
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Change the URLs to https to resolve the issue.

Comment: Since I'm using ant + ivy instead of maven I don't have a pom.xml file. I do have an ivy.xml, an ivysettings.xml, and build.xml file but I could not find anywhere that uses http instead of https. The one line I have that references the maven reporsitory is this found in the build.xml file:

 <get src="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.install.version}/ivy-${ivy.install.version}.jar"

Comment: I'm not familiar with ivy but try prefixing the link with https:// on the src attribute

Comment: Yes I fixed the problem by changing:
<ibiblio name="Maven" m2compatible="true" /> to
<ibiblio name="Maven" root="https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" m2compatible="true" />

in my ivysettings file.

for some reason ivy defaults to using http instead of https I guess.

Comment: The OP specifically asks for Ant. which is a different build tool. This answer is not useful. Instead, this is a useful answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61116241/611526